# zIndex isn't working for a react native project

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to have a card shown on top of a card in React Native and set `zIndex = 1` for the top card and `zIndex = 0` for the bottom card and placed them in a view like below:

```
<View style={{paddingVertical: MARGIN_1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  {this.props.subscribed ? (
    <CardSubscribe
      style={{zIndex: 2}}
    />
  ) : (null)}
  {this._renderTextItems()}
</View>
```

However, there's no overlap between two cards. The bottom card starts after the top card:

[image]

I have also tried to debug with inspector and it shows the top card has the property of `zIndex = 1` :

[image]

and the bottom card has the property of `zIndex = 0` :

[image]

I have also tried to place the top card after the bottom card but it just shows below the bottom card, like `zIndex` isn't doing anything. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In **React Native** we have `position: relative` by default. If you want to make the correct use of `zIndex`, you might need to add `position: 'absolute'`, for them to overlap as described in your use case.

For example:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
               <View style={{width: 200, height: 200, zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
               <View style={{width: 200, height: 200, zIndex: 2, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
 </View>
```

Answer (score 64):

z-index working fine in IOS. but again you will get isssue in android. In android z-index is not working you need to use elevation. But please do not forget to add z-index.

```
<TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                alignSelf: 'center',
                position: 'absolute',
                right: 10,
                top: 10,
                zIndex: 15,
                elevation: (Platform.OS === 'android') ? 50 : 0
              }}
              onPress={() => {}}
            >
              <Image
                source={require('dummy.png')}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: `elevation` fixed the problem for me. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks! I have been struggling with this issue and never could think that the elevation property could fix it. Thank you so much

Comment: I was lost until I saw this. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks man! It was a little tricky to guess that!.

Comment: elevation didnt work for me.. only reorder one on other working in android.
if I want that view 2 will be over view 1 (on top of view 1) then:
<View style={styles.view1}></View><View style={styles.view2} ></View>